# How to run PHP in safe mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, ubuntu-16.04

Some time ago the PHP safe mode has been deprecated. That's why, I can't use it.

I'm planning to run a game server for a client who rents from me and I will give a `directory-FTP` to him. However , it'll run PHP and some plugins may use functions like `unlink()` outside of their allowed directory, being able to delete other dangerous server files... and functions such as `exec()` or any malicious, dangerous function should be disabled.

For example, [Hostinger's hosting](https://www.hostinger.com) has what I'm looking for. They limit actions you can do and don't let you go outside your allowed directory using PHP, and functions such as `exec()` are disabled.

How can I do that?

Current Version : PHP7

Comment: I'd run a separate PHP pool as a different user with limited permissions. You might be able to do something similar with the web server.

Comment: How ? Please be more descriptive, I don't know how to run as different user and as of the disabled functions setting, some like `unlink()` are still needed and want them not to run outside the allowed directory, as I explained...

Answer (score 0):

The `php.ini` configuration file permits a [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) setting.

That said, don't give people you don't trust access to your servers.